# UDP packet capturing in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

Wireshark captures UDP packets in my LAN with follwoing details

```
Source IP            192.168.1.2
Destination IP      233.x.x.x
Source Port        24098
Destination Port      12074,12330
```

how can i capture it in c#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it myself

Here is my working code

```
class CAA
{

    private Socket UDPSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    private IPAddress Target_IP;
    private int Target_Port;
    public static int bPause;

    public CAA()
    {
        Target_IP = IPAddress.Parse("x.x.x.x");
        Target_Port = xxx;

        try
        {
            IPEndPoint LocalHostIPEnd = new
            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Target_Port);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, 1);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
            UDPSocket.Bind(LocalHostIPEnd);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, 0);
            UDPSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new
            MulticastOption(Target_IP));
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Recieve");
            Recieve();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void Recieve()
    {
        try
        {
            IPEndPoint LocalIPEndPoint = new
            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Target_Port);
            EndPoint LocalEndPoint = (EndPoint)LocalIPEndPoint;
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = UDPSocket;
            Console.WriteLine("Begin Recieve");
            UDPSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, ref LocalEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {

            IPEndPoint LocalIPEndPoint = new
            IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Target_Port);
            EndPoint LocalEndPoint = (EndPoint)LocalIPEndPoint;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceiveFrom(ar, ref LocalEndPoint);            



            client.BeginReceiveFrom(state.buffer, 0, state.BufferSize, 0, ref LocalEndPoint, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
    }


    public static void Main()
    {       
        CAA o = new CAA();        
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class StateObject
    {
        public int BufferSize = 512;
        public Socket workSocket;
        public byte[] buffer;

        public StateObject()
        {
            buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an old post. And, yes, this  comment is just a nit about a semantic foible --  some variable names in `ReceiveCallback` lend to confusion.  `EndReceiveFrom` fills in the `ref` parameter with the **Remote** endpoint information, not the local endpoint information.

Answer (score 8):

The [Winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/) library is one of the best ways to do this. I have experience in doing this in C# and it was really easy to work with this library.

This [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dotnetwinpcap.aspx) shows how to do it with C#.

Comment: Its WinPcap. Follow the above link. I think SharpPCap is a wrapped version and perhaps it will be more convenient to use.

Comment: Above is a multicast stream. Can i use simple .Net sockett classes to retrieve packets???

Comment: Using .NET classes such as UdpClient and TcpClient will ***not*** return the source and destination information you're looking for.  These sockets only return you the payload when you receive data from them.  The `LocalEndPoint` and `RemoteEndPoint` properties of the `Socket` class will work for TCP-based communication.  But for UDP, the `RemoteEndPoint` is not always what you want.  The source and destination addresses are contained in the IP header and the ports are in the TCP/UDP headers.  To get this data using a .NET socket, you have to collect using a "raw" socket.

Answer (score 8):

Wireshark actually uses Winpcap to do this, and as the other answer indicates, you can use it as well.

You can also use the `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` class and place it in promiscuous mode.  I use this to capture the IP traffic (e.g., TCP and UDP) from a given network interface.  Here's an example.

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

Socket socket =
    new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("X.X.X.X"), 0)); // specify IP address
socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024; // 2 megabytes
socket.ReceiveTimeout = 500; // half a second
byte[] incoming = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
byte[] outgoing = BitConverter.GetBytes(1);
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, incoming, outgoing);
```

Now that the socket is created and configured, you can use the `Receive()` method to start receiving data.  Each time you call `Receive()`, the returned buffer will contain an IP packet.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) for the breakout of the IPv4 header, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) for the UDP header, and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) for the TCP header.  If the *Protocol* field of the IP header contains a value of 17, then you have a UDP packet.

**NOTE**  Raw sockets on Windows require that you be an administrator on your local system.  The following language is contained in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(VS.85).aspx).

> To use a socket of type SOCK_RAW
>   requires administrative privileges.
>   Users running Winsock applications
>   that use raw sockets must be a member
>   of the Administrators group on the
>   local computer, otherwise raw socket
>   calls will fail with an error code of
>   WSAEACCES. On Windows Vista and later,
>   access for raw sockets is enforced at
>   socket creation. In earlier versions
>   of Windows, access for raw sockets is
>   enforced during other socket
>   operations.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am checking it. Meanwhile note that that above is a multicast stream (UDP).

Comment: above code gives exception
"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Comment: I forgot to mention that you have to have admin privileges on your local machine to create a "raw" socket like this.  I'm running this code inside a Windows service which is running under the SYSTEM account, so this issue doesn't bite me.  Also, if you are doing multicast UDP, creating a socket this way does **not** join the multicast group.  Thus, if you are behind a router, you are not guaranteed that the multicast traffic will be routed along the segment you're on.  In short, you may want to join the multicast group with a second socket to ensure that this "raw" socket will see the data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use WinPcap for raw packet capturing in C#, you can try [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com).
It is a wrapper for WinPcap in C++/CLI and C# for easily capturing (sniffing) and injecting raw packets and it also contains an easy to use packets interpretation framework.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pcap.Net in https://github.com/PcapDotNet

Especific exemple: https://github.com/PcapDotNet/Pcap.Net/wiki/Pcap.Net-Tutorial-Interpreting-the-packets

```
// Callback function invoked by libpcap for every incoming packet
    private static void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
    {
        // print timestamp and length of the packet
        Console.WriteLine(packet.Timestamp.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff") + " length:" + packet.Length);

        IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
        UdpDatagram udp = ip.Udp;

        // print ip addresses and udp ports
        Console.WriteLine(ip.Source + ":" + udp.SourcePort+ " -> " + ip.Destination + ":" + udp.DestinationPort);
    }
```

> Output:
>   `2009-09-12 11:25:51.117 length:84
>   10.0.0.8:49003 -> 208.67.222.222:53
>   2009-09-12 11:25:51.212 length:125
>   208.67.222.222:53 -> 10.0.0.8:49003
>   2009-09-12 11:25:54.323 length:80
>   10.0.0.8:39209 -> 208.67.222.222:53
>   2009-09-12 11:25:54.426 length:75
>   10.0.0.8:47869 -> 208.67.222.222:53
>   2009-09-12 11:25:54.517 length:236
>   208.67.222.222:53 -> 10.0.0.8:39209
>   2009-09-12 11:25:54.621 length:91
>   208.67.222.222:53 -> 10.0.0.8:47869`