# How to capture header of UDP packet in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am making an application in C#. In that application I am listening data on particular port. But while listening data on that port, I am getting that packet data but I also want to listen  header of that packet data (means sequence number,source port,destination port etc). The code for listening data is as:

```
 UdpClient client = null;
 IPEndPoint ipep = null;
 client = new UdpClient(9000); 
 ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,9000);

  byte[] data= = client.Receive(ref ipep);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271183/udp-packet-capturing-in-c-sharp please see this past SO post if it helps @Dany

Comment: Is there any other way than it?Please

Comment: Is there any other way of getting header of received packet instead of RAW socket?

Comment: sequence number -- there is no sequence number in UDP. source port -- you can use recvfrom (sorry, ReceiveFrom in C#). -- target port: that would be always 9000 in your example. The only thing you don't see is the UDP header checksum..